# Scalaz and scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala, scalaz

`OptionT[Future[_], A]` transformer needs implicit `Functor[Future]` in scope. But if evidence is moved to another file that doesn't have implicit `ExecutionContext` the compiler fails with error     `Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext.`. Is it possible to write a code that wouldn't have evidence definitions all over the place and will use `ExecutionContext` that's available at invocation of `OptionT`?

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Hello {
  implicit val ev = new Functor[scala.concurrent.Future] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: (A) => B): Future[B] = fa.map(f)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val task: Future[Option[String]] = Future { Some("hello") }
    val scream = (for( message <- OptionT(task)) yield message.toUpperCase()).run
    val msg = Await.result(scream, 10.seconds)
    println(msg.get)
  }
}
```

Comment: Implicits are often curried functions. You could probably specify a context explicitly to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the evidence require the execution context:

```
implicit def ev (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = 
  new Functor[scala.concurrent.Future] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: (A) => B): Future[B] = fa.map(f)
  }
```

This way the execution context need only be provided at invocation.